# Error when retrieving playlist tracks from spotifyr

Tags: r, spotify

I am trying to retrieve tracks from a df of playlists using spotifyr but I keep recieving the following error:

`Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE`

Here is my code below.

```
my_playlist <- get_user_playlists(spotify_id,
                              limit = 50,
                              offset = 0,
                              authorization = get_spotify_authorization_code(),
                              include_meta_info = FALSE)

tracks <- get_playlist_tracks(my_playlist)
```

The df `my_playlist` is working fine and has all the relevant components, links, uris, etc. But the function does not seem to be working. I have the spotify authorization token that I need to access and play around with the api. I have been able to get audio features from artists or albums, just not playlists. Any advice would be more than appreciated

I have been using this [link](https://msmith7161.github.io/what-is-speechiness/) as a guide following it step by step by to no avail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.